# Using Xming to show VMS display and receiving errors about fonts/color

Tags: windows-10, display, openvms, xming, vax

I am trying something new to me and have not found much information on the subject...
I am running Xming on a Windows 10 PC (this is on an isolated environment and cannot be connected to the internet) and sending a map program from VMS to it.
The connections are there, but while trying to show the display VMS gives up (times out).
I am able to see half of the drawing (not the correct color (only showing blue and black and an outline) and there is no fonts showing up).
VMS just reads 'display error'

I was able to use a software to analyze the packets and have received these errors below:

Request: Query Font, Open Font(There were several)
*souvenir-demi-r-normal--14-100-100-100-p-90-*

-*-menu-medium-r-normal--*-120-*-*-P-*-ISO8859-1

-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-120-*-*-P*-ISO8859-1

Reply: Bad Font, Bad Name (There were several)
(For bad font)
Error-badresourceid: 0x0020003f
Error-badresourceid: 0x0020003e
Error-badresourceid: 0x0020004e
Error-badresourceid: 0x00200078
Error-badresourceid: 0x002000a2

Request: Free Colors
Reply: Bad Access

Request:AllocColorCells, Stored Named Color
Reply: Bad Alloc, Bad Access

I need to resolve these issues, but not quite sure how. I am assuming/hoping/logistically thinking that if these are resolved my program will run fine.
My xming is running on one window, starting with no client, clipboard and no access control (These parameters cannot be changed for the purpose of what I am working on).

I have looked into font aliasing? thinking that may be able to fix my issues, but not sure which fonts to alias.. I have the Xming fonts on the PC in the correct folder,
but have read little about font aliasing, I know how to implement it, just not sure which fonts I need to alias (Also confused because in the Xming fonts each font has a
font.alias file). So at this point I'm not sure if I need font alias or add more fonts because some are missing on the PC?..

Thank you for any advice/solutions/help in advance.